# ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:34810

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client

I am reading Mastering Bitcoin book, and on:
https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch03.asciidoc#full_index_node

there is a call to bitcoin node:

```
$ curl --user myusername --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getblockchaininfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```

when I submit this command on a terminal, it asks for a password, which I copy and paste from `.cookie`

but there is an error on the bitcoin node cli:

```
ThreadRPCServer incorrect password attempt from 127.0.0.1:34810
```

A `.cookie` file is key value pair:

```
__cookie__:xxx
```

I tried copying both key and value as well as just value as a password, but still got the same error. Please help.

Comment: Are you using `__cookie__` as the username? Or something else? In general though, you shouldn't be using the `.cookie` file as it will change between restarts. You should define your own username and passphrase using the `rpcauth` option in the bitcoin.conf file.